# Android: updating an existing app on google play store using a patch file

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have an application on google play-store. The size of the apk is too large around 40MB due to some known reasons. So, whenever i update my app and upload the apk, users have to download entire 40 MB i suppose.

So, is it possible to release a patch instead of re-uploading the entire apk. Large applications whose size is in hundreds of MB's follow this approach, that is the user need not re-download hundreds of MB of data again. If this approach is possible in my scenario, then what code modifications should be included in my apk, such that next  release can just include a patch.

I have searched quite enough, but haven't found anything related. It shall be really helpful to me and others referring the post if anyone answers this query of mine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider creating another application and uploading it and make your main application use that other application. Such as they have MX Player application and MX ARM codec in the Google play. It is possible for one application to use features from the other one if they both, say, define the same custom security permission.

There is also apk extension mechanism http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Other than that I don't know

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the suggestion. But i'm really keen to know how developers of Need for Speed Most Wanted do it. They have the game size 550 MB, each time they add a new car to the game, we are provided with a patch like update which is some 40-50 Mb in size. Any idea about this mechanism??

Comment: Perhaps via apk extensions mechanism.http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html